# Value not displaying for Material2 Autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-autocomplete

I am trying to get the autocomplete to display one parameter of object but save another and so far it doesn't seem to be behaving.

Code is as per Material2 Autocomplete site: [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete)

The difference is that [value] i want to save 'option.Id' and not 'option'.

The error is that while it records the option.Id it doesn't actually display the value in input field (leaves it blank).

my-comp.html

```
<md-input-container>
   <input type="text" mdInput [formControl]="myControl" [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
   <md-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.Id">
      {{ option.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

my-comp.ts

```
class MyComp implements OnInit {
   myControl = new FormControl();
   options = [
     new User('Mary', 1),
     new User('Shelley', 2),
     new User('Igor', 3)
   ];
   filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

   ngOnInit() { 
      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
         .startWith(null)
         .map(user => user && typeof user === 'object' ? user.name : user)
         .map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.options.slice());
   }

   filter(name: string): User[] {
      return this.options.filter(option => new RegExp(`^${name}`, 'gi').test(option.name)); 
   }

   displayFn(user: User): string {
      return user ? user.name : user;
   }
}

class User {
name: string;
id: number;

constructor(name: string, id: number)
this.name = name;
this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: try `[ngValue]`

Comment: One small thing which might be causing the issue. `Id` used instead of `id` in ngfor loop.

Comment: ngValue throws template parsing error as its not part of md-options. Id is being set properly just value not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the autocomplete a model *(example: myModel)*:

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" [(ngModel)]="myModel">
   <md-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [ngValue]="option.Id">
      {{ option.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Here, `[ngValue]` gives `myModel` the value of `option.Id`.

When you retrieve the model `myModel` you will be getting `option.Id`.

If you need, you can help yourself by adding `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"` to your `<md-autocomplete>` in order to manipulate data in the component.

Comment: ngValue throws template parsing error as its not part of md-options

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in displayFn function, where its expecting User object as a parameter, but you are passing user.id which is a number and because of the mismatch, not value is getting passed to the view.

I have a working exmaple in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y44sQJfQ5rtu8ihLrHCs?p=preview).

```
displayFn(userId: number) {
      return userId;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter from `options` by using `displayWith` of `md-autocomplete` to find `user.name` based on `user.id` which is binded to `md-option`, here you need to use `bind(this)` in order to access data of component.

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
```

and do filter at `displayFn` function

```
displayFn(id: number): string {
  if (!id) return '';
  let index = this.options.findIndex(option => option.id === id);

  return  index === -1 ? '' : this.options[index].name;
}
```

refer **[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4qBbpEEPJC26TGLAdRMM?p=preview)**.

Comment: in your template you are using `Id` but in your `User` class it's `id`. I think this may also cause blank to be set and if you correct this typo, `user.id` will be setted to `md-input`.

Comment: I am trying to use json file , before reading json file the 'displayFn' method got executed. How can i achieve the passing values from dynamic