# How to display using [displayWith] in AutoComplete Material2

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material2

I have an `array` that comes from my API and I'm using [**Material2#AutoComplete**](https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete) to filter this... it's working so far, however I'm in trouble to display the another *property* instead of the *binded* value in *option*.

I know I have to use [`displayWith`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L51), however it isn't working as I'm expecting. The function called as `[displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">` just returns me the `id`, how can I get the full object and so return the `name` on function.

BTW, I still want to have the id binded in my **FormControl**.

Some code:

***Component:***

```
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredStates: any;

  states = [
    { 
      id: 1,
      name: 'Alabama'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'North Dakota'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Mississippi'
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredStates = this.filterStates('');
  }

  onKeyUp(event: Event): void {
    this.filteredStates = this.filterStates(event.target.value);
  }

  filterStates(val: string): Observable<any> {
    let arr: any[];
    console.log(val)
    if (val) {
      arr = this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s.name));
    } else {
      arr = this.states;
    }

    // Simulates request
    return Observable.of(arr);
  }

  displayFn(value) {
    // I want to get the full object and display the name
    return value;
  }
}
```

***Template:***

```xml
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="State" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.id">
    {{ state.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Basically, it's almost the same as [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070998/value-not-displaying-for-material2-autocomplete) (unfortunately both answers are incorrect or throw errors).

Here's the [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8lrmolKoKk3l10951vkS?p=info).

Comment: Same question with better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939310/binding-this-in-angular-material-autocomplete-displaywith-using-angular-5/55817526#55817526

Answer (score 39):

If you want the entire object to be binded with `md-options`, then you should bind to option with `state` and return `state.name` at `displayFn` and this way you don't have to bind `this`.

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
    {{ state.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

displayFn(state) {
  return state.name;
}
```

**[demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SA8Uv4fBkvrG3lMZnABU?p=preview)**.

---

and if you want to bind only `state.id` to `md-options`, you have to loop through `states` to find `state.name` based on `state.id` and this way binding `this` is needed.

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.id">
    {{ state.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

displayFn(id) {
  if (!id) return '';

  let index = this.states.findIndex(state => state.id === id);
  return this.states[index].name;
}
```

**[demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4tkNTmECvQkDIH8W2T8R?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, as I specified in question *"BTW, I still want to have the id binded in my FormControl."*, the **1st** option isn't what I want... I don't want to bind the full `object` (because back-end expects the `id`) to be sent in my form. And about the 2nd approach: It doesn't fill want I'm trying to achieve also... in plunker I used `states` hardcoded that way only for the purpose of demonstrating... in my application I have like 10 autocomplete all of them are `Observable`, I didn't subscribe them (and I don't want to), so I don't have the values that way.

Comment: @dev_054 some how complex than I imagined. according to your comments, maybe the 1st option is much fitter here for you can simply retrieve `satet.id`. :-)

Comment: Well, the problem here is that the `[displayWith]` is almost inflexible... I'll have to choice one of the 2 ways (both are workarounds for me)... anyway thanks.

Comment: @dev_054 agreed! glad to help :-)

Comment: Btw, I just created an [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4863) right now.

Comment: @pengyy i am trying to load the autocomplete values from server before retrieving  it's executing displaywith function is there any way to load function after retrieving

Comment: @Vignesh I have seen your comment(at another answer), sorry for I'm a little busy right now, will be back tomorrow. :-)

Comment: @Vignesh I have mocked autocomplete with loading json file and didn't get your problem. see https://plnkr.co/edit/puat2uhDDvjUbDgL8EjG?p=preview, hope I have got what you meant.  If you have further problems, maybe you should post a new question.

Comment: sorry @Pengyy .Based on ngModel value need to load value in textbox.  https://plnkr.co/edit/mxBHvaMpZWvm28E1DAKw?p=preview

Comment: @Pengyy before loading values from server the displaywith function gets executed check in plunker sample.

Comment: @Vignesh mmm... you have initialize `this.model` too early(before service got data back), you can check whether `states` have data or not, see fixed plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/kBZdT9rsKkm2X4oimjrh?p=preview. but still maybe `@angular/material` should do some improvements for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146528/discussion-between-vignesh-and-pengyy).

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but every one of the Plukr links in this article result in nothing more than a "Loading Material Docs example..." message  (and a bunch of JavaScript errors in the Console).  I'm genuinely not sure if my laptop's not set up correctly, or if these libraries have moved on, breaking all the existing code....  ;-(

Comment: @MikeGledhill many things has changed since I answered this question, I'll fix the examples links when I get some time.

Comment: using `[displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)"` "solution" works, but man do I feel dirty...

Comment: @BlackICE This is just another option in case you didn't bind the whole object to options of select and then you can access the component context to do the filter part.

Comment: I had to use `[displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">` today, but I also had to add "this" to the function like `displayFn(this, object:any) {`

Comment: @BlackICE There's nothing "dirty" about using `bind()`. It's a core JavaScript functionality to manually set function context. ;-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: it's very dirty when considering this simple alternative : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817526/16940