# Binding 'this' in Angular Material Autocomplete displayWith using Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I was trying to use the Material Angular autocomplete and I came across the displayWith function which can be apparently used to be the output that is displayed on selection. I wanted to call a custom function within the display function like

```
displayFn(id) {
 return this.getValue(id)
}
getValue(id) {
 /**return some string
}
```

**For the autocomplete**

```
<mat-autocomplete #autoOutlet="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of outletFilterOptions | async [value]="option.outletId">
   {{ option.outletName }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

As you see I am using the `id` as the model instead of the entire object.

When the display function returned an error that this.getValue is undefined I searched Stack Overflow for a solution and was suggested that I use something like `[displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)"`.

But unfortunately, that isn't working for me either. I am using **Angular material 5.1.0.**

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
displayFn = value => {
  // now you have access to 'this' 
  this.someMethod();
  return 'formatted display';
}
```

Comment: It was not obvious to me why this works. I learned that arrow functions differ in that they always establish "this" based on the scope where they are defined.

Comment: that saved me Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It is because of this is not binding to the component and its binding to mat-select option

[image][image]

NOw for using component's function, you have to use arrow function,  the preferable method or pass this from the HTML function

I will use the arrow function to use the component's function

Without arrow function

```
displayFn(data: any) {
    return data.Id?this.sometask(data):''
}
```

With arrow function

```
displayFn = (data: any) => {
    return data.Id?this.sometask(data):''
}
```

This work in my scenario and it worked in your scenario too.

Answer (score 4):

You could just change your template to be

```
<mat-autocomplete #autoOutlet="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn(id, this)">
```

Inside of templates `this` is a reference to your Component. Then just change your function to

```
displayFn(id, _this) {
  return _this.getValue(id)
}
```

If `[displayWith]` needs to be a function, you could create a property that returns your `displayFn` like this:

```
get createDisplayFn() {
  return (id) => {
    return this.getValue(id)
  }
}
```

and change your binding to `[displayWith]="createDisplayFn"`. As ES6 arrow function can't be rebinded, `this` should still be a reference to your component.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but I can't happen to pass the selected `id` with the displayFn. The second suggestion sets my display value with the function itself like `function { return this.... ` is printed in the DOM

Comment: The second option here (using a proxy function to return your function) worked for me.

Comment: @SriramJayaraman I guess, you forgot the `get` before the function definition

Answer (score 0):

Define `cThis = this` as a property of your class, and then use it inside your `displayFn` function:

`<mat-autocomplete #autoOutlet="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn(id, cThis)">`

---

```
cThis = this;
displayFn(id, cThis) {
 return cThis.getValue(id)
}
getValue(id) {
 /**return some string
}
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6opxw) that shows binding in `displayWith`

Comment: I checked out your suggestion but I am not able to pass the id from the DOM

Comment: Where is `id` coming from then?

Comment: The id is auto-generated by angular material without passing any such paramters

Comment: OK I see, what happens if you just do `[displayWith]="displayFn(cThis)"` ?

Comment: yes i get one param and that is is this binded to it

Comment: But then I assume `id` is undefined? If that's the case, could you not extract id from the `option` object?

Comment: yes! in that case id is undefined. `option` object is only the list, it is not the selected option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169445/discussion-between-bugs-and-sriram-jayaraman).

Answer (score 0):

You just missed an `undefined` check before using attribute.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)">

<mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user" >
    {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
</mat-option>

displayFn(user) {
    if (!user) return '';
    return user.name;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to call another method within the displayFn method.