# Angular 2+ mat-autocomplete shows [Object Object]

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I have `Angular 8` `mat-autocomplete` with `[displayWith]="getDropdownView"` where

```js
getDropdownView(option) {
    console.log("getDropdownView(): option:", option);
    return "abc";  // FOR TEST
    // return option.value;
}
```

For one page this works ok, but for another one this shows `[Object Object]`. There is such HTML code:

```html
<input matInput placeholder="Начните вводить..." [matAutocomplete]="auto" [id]="field.field"
    [value]="getDropdownValue(field.field)"
    (input)="loadDropdownData($event.target.value, field.field)">

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption
    (optionSelected)="onDropdownSelected($event.option.value, field.field)"
    [displayWith]="getDropdownView">

    <mat-option *ngIf="dropdownIsLoading[field.field]" class="is-loading">
        <mat-spinner diameter="50"></mat-spinner>
    </mat-option>

    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of dropdownData[field.field]" [value]="option" style="width: 300px">
       <span>{{ option.value }}</span>
       <small> | ID: {{option.id}}</small>
    </mat-option>

</mat-autocomplete>
```

Also *.ts has this method:

```js
getDropdownValue(field_name) {
    let id = this.model.data[field_name];
    for (let i in this.dropdownData[field_name]) {
      let option = this.dropdownData[field_name][i];
      if (option.id === id) {
        console.log("getDropdownValue(): option:", option);
        return option;
      }
    }
    console.log("getDropdownValue(): option: null");
    return null;
  }
```

Execution log when I change selected items via dropdown menu (without text input):

1. `getDropdownValue()` for input's `[value]` gets called multiple times with correct old item (to set composite object as autocomplete's chosen value);
2. `getDropdownView()` for mat-autocomplete's `[displayWith]` gets called with correct new item (to get shown value from **new** composite object);
3. `onDropdownSelected()` for mat-autocomplete's `(optionSelected)` gets called with correct new item (to inform *.ts that option has been chosen);
4. `getDropdownValue()` for input's `[value]` gets called multiple times again with correct new item.

How can I get right `displayWith` instead of `[Object Object]`?

Comment: can you check this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234290/how-to-display-using-displaywith-in-autocomplete-material2

Comment: can you share `getDropdownView`?

Comment: what do you get when you print your `option` on the console?

Comment: we get `[Object Object]` only when the value is of object type and not the literal. e.i. `{"someKey": "sameValue"}`; hence, what you get on the console will tell you what to return from the function.

Comment: @SandeepKumar `option` is like `{"id": 1, "value": "First opt"}`. I want to bind whole object to input but show only `option.value`.

Comment: this looks like an ideal case, except you are getting something else in the `getDropdownView(option)`.

Comment: @SandeepKumar `getDropdownView()` receives whole `option` object as shows `console.log()`, but something goes wrong and I can't understand where.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203907/discussion-between-sandeep-kumar-and-evgeny-nozdrev).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `[value]="getDropdownValue(field.field)"` from your `<input>`.

Take an array field and bind that to your input as a model, not as a value.
then on every new select, add the new value to the existing array.

To handle the pre-population: get the values in the constructor of your component and assign all of them to the array field.

Above solution is when you are not using `formControls`, if you use `formControls`, you can assign the values to the `formControl` field, that we just assigned to the array.

Comment: This fixed the problem, but: 1. How does this work? 2. Why on another page dropdown works with `[value]`?

Comment: `[value]` is used to bind a variable to your input field, which is not required when we are using auto-complete as auto-complete takes care of setting the selected value to the input thru `[matAutocomplete]="auto"`. I'm not sure how it's working on the other page, probably the binding there is not return any object, hence the auto-complete value is showing properly.

Comment: There is another problem: without `[value]` autocomplete's value can't be preselected when page opened.

Comment: can you share `getDropdownValue(field.field)`?

Comment: change your return statement to: `return option.value;` and keep `[value]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203962/discussion-between-evgeny-nozdrev-and-sandeep-kumar).